# ElasticSearch pick one product from each category with top score

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

I am trying to query ES index which contains product information, having product_id, category_id and variant_id fields. Each product belong to certain category and variant:

```
{
    "product_id" : "PRODUCT_12345",
    "category_id" : 1,
    "variant_id" : 5
}
```

I also have list of product_id and its scores:

`[{'product_id': 'PRODUCT_46831', 'score': 1}, {'product_id': 'PRODUCT_47139', 'score': 0.95}, {'product_id': 'PRODUCT_46833', 'score': 0.8999999999999999}, {'product_id': 'PRODUCT_46834', 'score': 0.8499999999999999}, {'product_id': 'PRODUCT_46835', 'score': 0.7999999999999998}]`

These scores are calculated using an algorithm and each product_id is present in ES. I want to filter the list such that only one product is selected from each category and variant. From each category and variant the product with highest score should be chosen. So for above list if `PRODUCT_46831, PRODUCT_47139, PRODUCT_46833` belong to `category 1`. `PRODUCT_46834, PRODUCT_46835` belongs to `category 2` . `PRODUCT_46831, PRODUCT_46834` belongs to `variant 1` and `PRODUCT_46833, PRODUCT_47139, PRODUCT_46835` belongs to `variant 2`, the grouping on category will create list `[PRODUCT_46831, PRODUCT_46834]`, since `PRODUCT_46831, PRODUCT_46834` are top scored product from there categories:

Further grouping `PRODUCT_46831, PRODUCT_46834` on variant_id will create result :

`[PRODUCT_46831]`

since `PRODUCT_46831, PRODUCT_46834` belong to same `variant id 1` and `PRODUCT_46831` has highest score in the list.

I tried using aggregation to form buckets for each category and then applying sort function with weight = score of product and picking top product, i was able to get list of products with top score in particular category_id , i am struggling to apply variant_id grouping on top of this list. Here is my query so far:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "functions": [
        {
                "field_value_factor": 
                {
                    "field": "item_id",
                    "factor": 0
                }
            },
        {
          "filter": { "term": { "id": "PRODUCT_46831" } },
          "weight": 1
        },
        {
          "filter": { "term": { "id": "PRODUCT_47139" } },
          "weight": 0.95
        },
        {
          "filter": { "term": { "id": "PRODUCT_46833" } },
          "weight": 0.9
        },
        {
          "filter": { "term": { "id": "PRODUCT_46834" } },
          "weight": 0.85
        },
        {
          "filter": { "term": { "id": "PRODUCT_46835" } },
          "weight": 0.8
        }
      ],
      "score_mode": "sum",
      "boost_mode": "sum",
      
  "query" : {
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [
      {
        "terms" : {
          "id" : [
            "PRODUCT_46831",
            "PRODUCT_47139",
            "PRODUCT_46833",
            "PRODUCT_46834",
            "PRODUCT_46835"
          ],
          "boost" : 0
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 0
  }
}
}
},
 "aggs" : {
      "category_id_max_product" : {
        "terms" : { "field": "category_id" },
        "aggs": {
            "max_score": {
              "top_hits": {
                "sort": [
                  {
                    "_score": {
                      "order": "desc"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "_source": {
                  "includes": ["_id", "category_id", "variant_id", "_score"]
                },
                "size": 1
              }
            }
          }
        }
   }
, "_source": ["_id", "category_id", "variant_id", "_score"]
, "size": 0
}
```

the documents :

```
{
        "_index" : "search_entities",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "PRODUCT_46831",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "category_id" : 2296,
          "variant_id" : 564819,
          "id" : "PRODUCT_46831"
        }
},
{
        "_index" : "search_entities",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "PRODUCT_47139",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "category_id" : 2296,
          "variant_id" : 723311,
          "id" : "PRODUCT_47139"
        }
},
{
        "_index" : "search_entities",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "PRODUCT_46833",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "category_id" : 2296,
          "variant_id" : 723311,
          "id" : "PRODUCT_46833"
        }
},
{
        "_index" : "search_entities",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "PRODUCT_46834",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "category_id" : 3321,
          "variant_id" : 564819,
          "id" : "PRODUCT_46834"
        }
},
{
        "_index" : "search_entities",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "PRODUCT_46835",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "category_id" : 3321,
          "variant_id" : 723311,
          "id" : "PRODUCT_46835"
        }
},
```

Comment: So does `PRODUCT_46831` have two different values for `variant_id`?  Can you provide the sample documents for your requirements instead of enumerating them, it would mek it easier to reproduce your case without error?

Comment: @Val corrected the case. Also added the sample doc

Comment: Thanks, but I meant all sample docs that you mention in your question, so it's easier for people to help you and not have to guess your data.

Comment: @Val added all the docs, updated the so far query as well, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am able to do it using scripted metric, Not the optimsed one , but works:

```
{
  
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": { "term": { "id": "PRODUCT_229648" } },
          "weight": 0.9
        },
        {
          "filter": { "term": { "id": "PRODUCT_108882" } },
          "weight": 0.95
        },
        {
          "filter": { "term": { "id": "PRODUCT_108881" } },
          "weight": 0.8
        },
        {
          "filter": { "term": { "id": "PRODUCT_172062" } },
          "weight": 0.95
        },
        {
          "filter": { "term": { "id": "PRODUCT_172060" } },
          "weight": 0.9
        },
        {
          "filter": { "term": { "id": "PRODUCT_216303" } },
          "weight": 0.95
        },
        {
          "filter": { "term": { "id": "PRODUCT_220975" } },
          "weight": 0.96
        }
      ],
      "boost_mode": "sum",
      
  "query" : {
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [
      {
        "terms" : {
          "id" : [
            "PRODUCT_229648",
            "PRODUCT_108882",
            "PRODUCT_108881",
            "PRODUCT_172062",
            "PRODUCT_172060",
            "PRODUCT_216303",
            "PRODUCT_220975"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true
  }
}
}
}, 
"aggs": {
  "intentPathsCountAgg": {
            "scripted_metric": {
                "init_script": """state.messagesList = new ArrayList();
                  state.allVariantMap = new HashMap();
                  state.variantMap = new HashMap();
                  state.categoryMap = new HashMap();
                  state.emptyVariantMap = new ArrayList();
                  """,
                "map_script": """
                double score = _score;
                String key = String.valueOf(doc['variant_group_id'].value);
                Map map = [
                              'score' : score,
                              'category_id' : String.valueOf(doc['category_brand_id'].value),
                              'product_id' : doc['item_id'].value
                           ];
                
                if (state.variantMap.containsKey(key)) {
                  if (state.variantMap.get(key).score < score) {
                     state.variantMap.put(key, map);
                  }
                }
                else {
                     state.variantMap.put(key, map);
                }
                """,
                "combine_script": """
                return state.variantMap;
                """,
                "reduce_script": """
                  Map categoryMap = new HashMap();
                  for (state in states) {
                    for (String key : state.keySet()) {
                      String categoryKey = state.get(key).category_id;
                      double score = state.get(key).score;
                      long productId = state.get(key).product_id;
                      Map map = [
                                'score' : score,
                                'product_id' : productId
                             ];
                      if (categoryMap.containsKey(categoryKey)) {
                        if (categoryMap.get(categoryKey).score < score) {
                           categoryMap.put(categoryKey, map);
                        }
                      }
                      else {
                           categoryMap.put(categoryKey, map);
                      }
                    }
                  }
                  return categoryMap;
                """
            }
        }
}
    
   
, "_source": ["_id", "category_id", "variant_group_id", "item_id", "id"]
, "size": 0
}
```